Proof that a random variable is constant over certain sets in the sample space
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Pr)$ be a probability space and consider a random element $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{E}) \to (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{E})$. The sigma-algebra generated by $X$ is
$$\sigma(X) = \{ X^{-1}(B) \mid B \in \Sigma \} \subset \mathcal{F}$$
Consider now a random variable $Y: (\Omega,\sigma(X)) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ that is only $\sigma(X)$ measurable.
It seems evident that $Y$ must be a.e. constant over the sets $A_x := X^{-1}(\{x\})= \{\omega \mid X(\omega)=x\}$, where we have assumed that $\mathcal{E}$ contains the singletons.
One way to show this result is by using the "Doob–Dynkin lemma
" (a.k.a factorization lemma) to write $Y = g \circ X$ for some measurable function $g: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, for any $\omega,\omega'\in A_x$, $Y(\omega)=g(X(\omega))=g(x)=g(X(\omega'))=Y(\omega')$.
I am wondering if there is a more direct proof of this result that avoids invoking the factorization lemma? Perhaps we can argue that $A_x$ are atoms of $\sigma(X)$, and that a measurable function on an atom is a.e. constant with value $k$ that satisfies $k \Pr(A_x) = \int_{A_x}Y(\omega)\Pr(\mathrm{d}\omega)$.

Suppose there are $\omega,\omega'\in A_x$ such that $Y(\omega)\neq Y(\omega')$. Take disjoint intervals $I$ and $I'$ containing $Y(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega')$ respectively. Then $A_x\cap Y^{-1}(I)$ is a proper nonempty subset of $A_x$ and such a set cannot be of the form $X^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{x\in B}A_x$.

Suppose that $X^{-1}(\{x\})\neq\emptyset$, otherwise it is obvious.
Let $\omega\in X^{-1}(\{x\})$ and $y=Y(\omega)$. By definition, $X^{-1}(\{x\})\cap Y^{-1}(\{y\})\in\sigma(X)$. So there exists $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ such that $$X^{-1}(\{x\})\cap Y^{-1}(\{y\})=X^{-1}(B).$$
Then
$$
X^{-1}(B\cap\{x\}^\complement)=X^{-1}(B)\cap X^{-1}(\{x\}^\complement)=X^{-1}(\{x\})\cap Y^{-1}(\{y\})\cap X^{-1}(\{x\}^\complement)=\emptyset.
$$
We deduce that $X^{-1}(B\cap \{x\})=X^{-1}(B)\neq\emptyset$, hence $B\cap\{x\}\neq\emptyset$, or equivalently $x\in B$. Therefore
$$
X^{-1}(\{x\})\subset X^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(\{x\})\cap Y^{-1}(\{y\}),
$$
or equivalently $X^{-1}(\{x\})\subset Y^{-1}(\{y\})$, which proves the claim.
